# What are your opinions on Salesforce Functions? What about the future of APEX?

Tags: apex, salesforce-functions

So, given that SF Functions are GA now, and people can write Functions in Java / JS / [...], what are your opinions about Functions?

Will that make it into the core product and sooner or later replace APEX as a language? To me, it seems APEX lacks a lot of functions all the other high level languages have (hint: reflection), other features took years, almost decades to implement (hint: switch/case). Do you think that APEX will be replaced sooner or later?

Answer (score 7):

Chris Peterson and other high-level employees have been asked similar questions, and the answer from all of them is "no, Apex is not being replaced by Salesforce Functions." While Functions are a shiny new toy, they were never meant to be a replacement for Apex. They provide additional compute power, of course, but this carries a price tag. There's restrictions on how much you can run at once, how much you can run overall, the fact that this is a paid upgrade, etc. Salesforce Functions are basically a built-in way to call Heroku or something from within Apex. In addition, dropping Apex means that many millions of lines of code would have to be ported to new languages, costing billions in the process. It's simply not feasible for Functions to be a replacement for Apex.